# Connect to homestead mysql from host machine

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server on my Homestead (vagrant) setup. I don't have any problems SSH-ing inside it, and I can use it's command line mysql without problems. Note that I'd like to connect to it from my host machine using MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 14.10

Here are my settings:

[image]

As you can see I've added my private ssh key. I don't think there is an ssh password set. The mysql username and passwords though are 100% correct.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit old question but I had problem with connection and maybe somebody else will have it. These are working parameters for connection:

[image]

- Homestead version: laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 2.1.0)
- Vagrant version: 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to SSH; check your homestead.yaml file for your ip, default = 192.168.10.10 - then just connect straight using the default username/password: 'homestead' and 'secret'

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to create an SSH tunnel to your local machine? That doesn't make sense. You wouldn't need SSH at all for that. I rather assume you have a remote server to which you want to connect, right? So use that IP address instead for SSH. If the MySQL server is on the same box as the SSH remote point then the loopback address is ok, otherwise change the value to the IP address of the remote MySQL server.

Comment: with vagrant / homestead, it does make sense.